# How to Change the UIAlertAction button Color in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I've a UIAlertController and I've a bunch of UIAlertAcion Buttons. Now I need to show one button with other Color rather than the same color.

For Ex

> Button1
>
> Button2
>
> Button3
>
> Button1 and button3 should be in blue
>
> and
>
> button2 should be in red.

Is it possible ? How?

Just Throw your thoughts
...

**My Code:**

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Food Menu" message:@"Select the MenuItem" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
for(int i= 0; i<[menus count];i++){

  UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[menu objectAtIndex:i] style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction* action){
             [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
             //do SomeWork

          }];

          if(i==currentIndex){
              //Put button Color Red
             }
           else{
             //put button color Blue
             }
          [actionSheet addAction:action];
       }

       UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction* action){
          [actionSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
       }];

       [actionSheet addAction:cancel];


  [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You need to write your own view to achieve this

Comment: What do u mean by that.. U mean Another container View... Or someting else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

do like change the alert style:`UIAlertActionStyleDestructive`

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                          alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle
                          message:alertMessage
                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction 
        actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
                  NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                }];

 UIAlertAction *resetAction = [UIAlertAction
         actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Reset", @"Reset action")
                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive 
                 handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                 {
                   NSLog(@"Reset action");
                 }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction 
        actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
                  NSLog(@"OK action");
                }];

[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:resetAction];
[alertController addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```